# Is the Many-Worlds Interpretation consistent with our best understanding of time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, relativity, quantum-interpretations, determinism

Einstein's theory of relativity implies a [B-theory of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-theory_of_time). Deterministic interpretations of quantum mechanics such as the Many-Worlds would seem to be consistent with the B-theory. Regardless of whether time is fundamental or is described by the B-theory, does the MWI have a better explanatory scope than indeterministic interpretations?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better suited to philosophy.SE.

Comment: A physical theory does not imply metaphysical nonsense. "Is time A-theory or B-theory?" is a meaningless question, its only value is in figuring out which interpretation helps you understand relativity and physics better.

Comment: There is no absolute time in relativity, so whatever philosophical theory of time one may come up with has to be more complex that either A or B-theories, which are different perspectives on a singly parametrized time dimension. In 4D spacetime, one can not single out a specific time dimension. Different foliations are always possible. The relevant concept is the causal structure, which is absolute.

Comment: See http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.2866 for details concerning my above comment.